# full size picture has white border, why?

Tags: swiftui

i have this code here and i get this white "border" on top which i do not want.
Does anybody know why i get it and how to get rid of it?

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
struct PicTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        ZStack {

            VStack {
                Text("a")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .background(Color.red)
                Text("b")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .background(Color.green)
            }
        }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        .background(Image("laguna")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill())
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/offsetshape/3270918-edgesignoringsafearea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it goes

[image: demo]

```
static var previews: some View {
    ZStack {

        VStack {
            Text("a")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .background(Color.red)
            Text("b")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .background(Color.green)
        }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) // << here !!
    .background(
        Image("large_image")
            .resizable()
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)              // << here !!
            .scaledToFill()
    )
}
```

Comment: i didn't know i could set edgesIgnoringSafeArea to image, i always set to zstack or hstack ....thanks!!!