# ZStack has extra space at the top

Tags: swiftui

The following code show weird extra space at the top. Anyone know what's the issue?

```
ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            Image(imageName)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .scaleEffect(imageScale)
                .blur(radius: imageScale > 1 ? 5 : 0)
                .animation(.easeOut)
}
.frame(width: selected ? UIScreen.main.bounds.width : width ,
       height: selected ? UIScreen.main.bounds.height : height)
.cornerRadius(30)
.shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3), radius: 15, x: 0, y: 20)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [full size picture has white border, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60819757/full-size-picture-has-white-border-why)

Comment: @Asperi no it didn't fix the issue for me!

Comment: Would you provide testable demo code - above code has many dependencies? Btw, if remove all dependencies in your code and add `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)` as a last modifier - no extra space at top. Just in case. Tested with Xcode 11.4.

Comment: try to take out .cornerRadius(30)
.shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3), radius: 15, x: 0, y: 20)

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the solution. It's `.cornerRadius(30)` that cause the problem. Adding `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` will not fix the issue unless you remove `.cornerRadius(30)`. I hope this answer help someone else.